# Read and echo a single line from file descriptor on demand in bash

Tags: bash, io

This was prompted by a code golf scenario, but it's a general programming question as well.

I've got a bash script that does not use stdin directly, so I'm repurposing it to produce a value on demand during a loop:

```
exec< <(command here)
```

The loop (over the command line arguments) will *conditionally* need a value from the new stdin, and it needs to `echo` it immediately. I'd like to reduce the number of commands involved, ideally just reading a single line and echoing it directly.

```
read v
echo $v
```

obviously works, but it feels... indirect, like doing:

```py
line = line.readline().rstrip('\n')
print(line)
```

in Python instead of directly passing the input to `print`, e.g.:

```py
print(line.readline().rstrip('\n'))
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is the only way to read and echo a line to read it into a variable, then echo the variable?

A simple MCVE, where I'm wondering if there is a *single* command that can replace `read v && echo $v`:

```
exec < <(tr ' ' \\n<<<'10 100 1000')

for i in 1 0 2 0 3 0 4; do
    if ((i == 0)); then
        read v && echo $v  # Replaced with just head -1, this echoes 10 the first time around, then echoes nothing on subsequent passes
    else
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU5BbsMwDLvnFQQ2NAnQAc62W91P9NyLGyuzhlZuLafb71PHxUaBBwmkyJPTsCz0SyMsbJcT2jLHo1hr28FgMJWm7ZtmigkMFgwweC/8KPzcwccGBTyh6xj7PUzf75ADSb2vSOQ87thsQGOIeL0DLzjQ9exG8vjhHPA9a0ZYdW/DtrhZq5a05K/PMHEqiswXgktxFr@tGX8qicUjX4gCnU9Kt5kk4@pUSWsPOiv9F3rW4LpP3PgotCwP)

---

To be clear, I actually found a solution to this for the specific golf problem (where I was ignoring the loop variable whenever I needed a line, so I could just `read` into the loop variable and then echo it the same way I'd have had to do if I couldn't replace it), in ungolfed form:

```
for i in 1 0 2 0 3 0 4; do
    if ((i == 0)); then
        read i
    fi
    echo $i
done
```

But it still feels weird that there isn't a command like `read_one_line` that pulls a single line from stdin and echoes it directly.

Comment: @shellter Process substitution also uses a subprocess.

Comment: @shellter: I have no problem with subprocesses, so long as they can read from the parent's (replaced) stdin. But `echo $(read v)` definitely doesn't work, `read` doesn't echo what it reads, so `$(read v)` expands to the empty string (while setting `v` silently), and `echo` has nothing to echo.

Comment: @ShadowRanger There's no concept in Bash where value is returned from a function or a builtin. Data is always communicated through a variable.

Comment: @konsolebox: Well, "return" here would just mean "echo to stdout"; obviously functions and command line utilities don't return anything but their exist status, but the functional equivalent to "return" of any other data is "writing it to stdout". If I wanted to echo the whole of stdin at once, I could run an unadorned `cat` for instance. Thinking about `cat` just jogged my memory and made me check if `head -1` would do what I wanted, but it looks like it either consumes or closes stdin if I do it, so while it reads one line, it also means all the other lines are discarded.

Comment: Can you post complete example that will allow a solution to be tested ?

Comment: @dash-o: Done. As I mentioned at the bottom, the specific case I needed it for had a more elegant solution (which I also included, just for completeness), but `head -1` didn't work for repeated reads anywhere I tried it (RHEL 7, TIO's system, or an Alpine 3.17 image). To be clear, not looking for golfing assistance precisely, nor looking for "how can I do this with some combination of tools?" (where `read` + `echo` is the obvious solution). I'm just trying to make sure I didn't overlook some existing all-in-one command/tool that would read a line at a time on demand.

Comment: I was intrigued by this problem. Spent more time on it. The Short answer - issue is with the way stdin is setup (exec ...). works OK if input is coming from a file. I've opened extra answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the 'head' command:

```
echo "$(head -1)"
```

Or for a solution without executing another program, use a function. something like below:

```
function readline {
    read v && echo "$v"
}

# Print next line from standard input
readline
```

And then:

Comment: Yeah, as I already mentioned in the comments, `head -1` doesn't do the trick; the first time it is run, it reads a single line, but it closes or consumes or otherwise denies access to the rest of stdin from then on, so you can't read a *second* line. The function approach works, but as I noted, I was looking to reduce the number of commands (this was for code golf, where more commands is worse, and wrapping them in a function when you just do it once anyway doesn't help), which really means it needs to be a built-in or part of coreutils. The function is fine normally, just not for golf.

Comment: If you want one liner, ‘read v && echo $v’ should qualify. The function simple give you a friendly name. I am not sure why head do yo use, but on RH7, head does not consume anything beyond the first line

Answer (score 0):

I'm intigued by the fact that 'head -1' did not work here. did more digging - see explanation (but not a better solution).

Executing simplified version of the OP test against a file produce the intended result (Alpine, Ubunto 20.4), but produces only 10 using pipe input.

```
#exec < <(tr ' ' \\n<<<'10 100 1000')
# x.txt has 3 lines: 10 100 1000
exec < x.txt
head -1
head -1
head -1
```

Running strace reveal how 'head' is working: head is reading blocks (8192) - for efficient processing - an uses "seek" to move back in the file, to put back any unprocessed input for other readers.

```
read(0, "10\n100\n1000\n", 8192)        = 12
lseek(0, -9, SEEK_CUR)
```

Smart solution for files - which unfortunately does not work for other cases.

Trying to change the input buffer for head (stdbuf) does not work - probably head is forcing the buffer size explictly.

Bottom line:

- If possible to use file input - head can be used as a replacement for reading one liner.
- If input is coming from non-file (socket, pipe, ...) - only solution is to use a replacement where buffering can be controlled (bash read/echo, or similar).